# remove caching of block

Tags: template, blocks, cache

I've tried:

```
<block type="page/html_topmenu" name="ajaxCart" as="ajaxCart" template="page/html/ajaxCart.phtml">
    <action method="unsetData"><key>cache_lifetime</key></action>
    <action method="unsetData"><key>cache_tags</key></action>
</block>
```

and:

```
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('ajaxCart', false); ?>
```

Neither seem to stop the caching of this template, any suggestions?

Comment: i not understand your question

Comment: @AshvinMonpara a part of my page is cached.  I'd like to remove this part from the cache such that this part is dynamically constructed at each pageview and isn't persistent between sessions.

Comment: disbled you cashe block in admin

Comment: @AshvinMonpara what?  how?  I can't disable FPC.

Comment: i not  FPC means

Comment: @AshvinMonpara Full Page Cache

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try this.

```
<block type="page/html_topmenu" name="ajaxCart" as="ajaxCart" template="page/html/ajaxCart.phtml">
    <action method="setCacheLifeTime"></action>
</block>
```

Setting cache life time to `NULL` force cache to turn off (in theory). However I didnt try this before.

But the call `echo $this->getChildHtml('ajaxCart', false)` should work as far as I know. After doing above steps and make sure the above calling is using, then try to FLUSH THE CACHE from backend and then test again.

Comment: If I make it to India I definitely owe you a Kingfisher.

Comment: pack me one then :) which one worked ? layout update or flush cache ??

Answer (score 2):

There are other ways to manage caching for specified blocks, but the technique is a little more involved and allows you to set caching expiration on blocks.

```
class myNameSpace_myModule_Block_View extends Mage_Core_Block_Template {     
    protected function _construct() {
        $this->addData(array(
            'cache_lifetime'    => 120,
            'cache_tags'        => array(Mage_Catalog_Model_Product::CACHE_TAG),
        ));
    }
```

}

reference link:-http://wabism.com/magento-bypass-caching-for-individual-block/

Comment: so in this case i'd set the cache lifetime to 0 ?

Comment: yes easymoden00b

Comment: this technique doesn't work.  this block is still cached and is persistent between sessions.